# Append coordinate to MapBox MGLPolyline

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, unsafe-pointers

I am trying to append a coordinate to a line that I am annotating a MapBox map with.

`MGLPpoyline` has the following function for appending coordinates:

```
appendCoordinates(_ coords: UnsafePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>, count: UInt)
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to pass a single coordinate point to the above function. The UnsafePointer bit has me going bananas. I've been looking all over the net but any solution I tried ends up with the following runtime error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I have just a regular `CLLocationCoordinates2D` instance at hand, which is verified to contain valid coordinates at the time of the function call.

Here's one of the things I've tried:

```
let coord = currentLocation!.coordinate // Verified valid
var coords: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [coord]
aLine.appendCoordinates(&coords, count:UInt(coords.count))  // Unexpectedly found nil...
```

btw, the following runs perfectly fine:

```
var line = MGLPolyline(coordinates:&coords, count:UInt(coords.count))
```

My apologies if I'm missing the obvious but I'm kinda new to Swift.

Any help or examples of the above function in use would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where does `aLine` come from, is it nil?

Comment: Turns out there was a race condition that executed the code above before `aLine` was initialized. Quite embarrassing but thanks for pointing to the right direction! I voted to close this question as it has no real value as it stands.